# How to write oracle query to get the employee details as on future date?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a employee table and employee update table as shown in the following image. Employee table always holds the current details of any employees.

While the employee update table holds the updates which are going to happen to the employee in some future date.

e.g. Employee james currently work in india but from 1st may he will be transfered to germany. So from 1st may his region, country and city will change.

I need to pull out a report to see what will be employee details as on 10th may. In this case all the employees with the updates before 1oth may should be shown with their new latest values.

[image]

Like region , country and city, I have few other fields which may have updates for the employee.

It might also be possible that some employees may not have any updates then their current record should be shown.

Is it possible to do this query?

I will be needing this report very frequently, so is it better idea to have result of this query as a view which then can be queried for reports?

Edit : -

Following is the query i have tried so far as answered by Glenn

```
WITH eff_emps AS ( 
SELECT 
    emp_id, firstname, region_id, country_id, city, effective_date   
FROM 
  bi_employee 

UNION 

SELECT 
  x.employee_id, 
  e.firstname, 
  CAST(MAX(x.region_id) as number) AS region_id, 
  CAST(MAX(x.country_id) as number) AS country_id, 
  MAX(x.city) AS city, 
  x.effective_date   
FROM ( 
      SELECT 
          employee_id, effective_date                ,
          CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'REGION_ID' THEN NEW_VALUE ELSE NULL END AS region_id               ,
          CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'COUNTRY_ID' THEN NEW_VALUE ELSE NULL END AS country_id                ,
          CASE WHEN COLUMN_NAME = 'CITY' THEN NEW_VALUE ELSE NULL END AS city            
      FROM bi_employee_update 
) x ,Bi_employee e   

WHERE e.emp_id = x.employee_id   
GROUP BY 
    x.employee_id, e.firstname, x.effective_date 
) 

SELECT *   FROM eff_emps f   
WHERE effective_date = ( 
  SELECT 
      MAX(effective_date)  
  FROM eff_emps 
  WHERE 
    emp_id = f.emp_id 
    AND effective_date <= TO_DATE('2012-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')    )
```

Comment: u need exactly a query? or procedure sort of things also ok?

Comment: @TFool. vIEW OR PROCEDURE anything will work.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:  Substantially revised.**

The first solution did not consider issues that arise from individual fields changing at different times.  It was only concerned with applying the most recent update onto the original effective_date values.

This is a rewrite of that answer, going back, so that each field that is being changed is considered individually, rather than jointly.

All sql is demonstrated at sqlfiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca4f4/6

---

We start off by getting the most recent change for any single field.  We can accomplish that with this:

```
select *
  from ( select empid, when, what from updates
  where when <= to_date('2012-05-10', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
  ) pivot_data
pivot ( max(when)
       for what in ('region' as max_region_date, 
                    'city' as max_city_date, 
                    'country' max_country_date)
);
```

This does a pivot table, to consider each field separately and gives the output of the maximum date that is less than or equal to the effective date of the report.  Note that as this pivot table is added to the larger query, it is only place where the Report Date is embedded.

To add more data, to your original set, let's use:

```
EMPID   NEW     WHAT    WHEN
1       germany region  May, 01 2012
1       germany country May, 01 2012
1       münchen city    May, 01 2012
2       boston  city    June, 01 2012
2       canada  country July, 01 2012
2       toronto city    July, 01 2012
2       vancouver   city    August, 01 2012
```

So, if you run the above query for a report date of 15.August, you get:

```
EMPID   MAX_REGION_DATE MAX_CITY_DATE   MAX_COUNTRY_DATE
1       May, 01 2012    May, 01 2012    May, 01 2012 
2       (null)          August, 01 2012 July, 01 2012
```

The (null) represents that region for empid = 2 has no entries in updates.  And the two other dates for empid = 2, represent the most recent change date for that field.

Now, we need to convert this to the `new` value at that date for each field.  That can be done w/ something like this:

```
select distinct u1.empid,
   (select u2.new from updates u2
    where u2.what = 'region'
      and u2.empid = u1.empid
      and u2.when = max_dates.max_region_date
    ) region, max_dates.max_region_date,
   (select u3.new from updates u3
    where u3.what = 'country'
      and u3.empid = u1.empid
      and u3.when = max_dates.max_country_date
    ) country, max_dates.max_country_date,
   (select u4.new from updates u4
    where u4.what = 'city'
      and u4.empid = u1.empid
      and u4.when = max_dates.max_city_date
    ) city, max_dates.max_city_date
from updates u1
left join 
  (select *
   from ( select empid, when, what from updates
          where when <= to_date('2012-07-15', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
        ) pivot_data
    pivot ( max(when)
        for what in ('region' as max_region_date, 
                    'city' as max_city_date, 
                    'country' max_country_date)
       )
   ) max_dates on max_dates.empid = u1.empid;
```

Where I have embedded the pivot table output above as a derived table, and then am individually selecting out each field value that corresponds to the specific date.

Running this with a report on 15.August gives:

```
EMPID REGION    MAX_REGION_DATE    COUNTRY    MAX_COUNTRY_DATE  CITY       MAX_CITY_DATE
2     (null)    (null)             canada     July, 01 2012     vancouver August, 01 2012 
1     germany   May, 01 2012       germany    May, 01 2012      münchen   May, 01 2012
```

For employee 2, we see that value of the country is canada, which was updated on 01.July, whereas the most recent city, Vancouver, came later, on 01.August.

Now, we need to combine this with a query against employee:

```
select e.empid, e.name,
  (coalesce( u.region, e.region)) region,
  (coalesce( u.city, e.city)) city,
  (coalesce( u.country, e.country)) country
from employee e
left join (
  select distinct u1.empid,
   (select u2.new from updates u2
    where u2.what = 'region'
      and u2.empid = u1.empid
      and u2.when = max_dates.max_region_date
    ) region, max_dates.max_region_date,
   (select u3.new from updates u3
    where u3.what = 'country'
      and u3.empid = u1.empid
      and u3.when = max_dates.max_country_date
    ) country, max_dates.max_country_date,
   (select u4.new from updates u4
    where u4.what = 'city'
      and u4.empid = u1.empid
      and u4.when = max_dates.max_city_date
    ) city, max_dates.max_city_date
  from updates u1
  left join 
    (select *
     from ( select empid, when, what from updates
            where when <= to_date('2012-08-15', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
          ) pivot_data
     pivot ( max(when)
       for what in ('region' as max_region_date, 
                    'city' as max_city_date, 
                    'country' max_country_date)
       )
  ) max_dates on max_dates.empid = u1.empid
) u on u.empid = e.empid
order by e.empid;
```

The biggest part of this is the derived table, which was shown earlier.  The rest is a join against `employee`, and then 'coalesce`ing to either take the updated value, or the current value in employee if the update value is`null`.

This results in:

```
EMPID    NAME    REGION    CITY      COUNTRY
1        james   germany   münchen   germany
2        mike    americas  vancouver canada
```

when using a report date of 15.August.  You can validate other dates against my test data (or adding your own) at the sqlfiddle given above.

Now, a final issue.  The above assumed that you have data integrity constraints to validate that updates are only in the future -- once an update was applied to the employee table (thus updating it's effective_date field), that row is eliminated from the updates table.  That is, that updates consists only of **unapplied** changes.

If we want to account for that case, we need to check it in the select on an individual basis by field again.  Modify the above select to:

```
select e.empid, e.name,
  (coalesce( (case 
                when (u.max_region_date > e.effective_date) 
                then u.region
              end),
            e.region)) region,
  (coalesce( (case 
                when (u.max_city_date > e.effective_date) 
                then u.city
              end),
            e.city)) city,
  (coalesce( (case 
                when (u.max_country_date > e.effective_date) 
                then u.country
              end),
            e.country)) country
from . . . . . the from in the previous query above . . .
```

In my case, you get the same output as before.

---

I should add, I agree w/ Glenn about not using the reserved words `when` and `new` in your column names.  (Though I left them in my sample.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you said about the caveat, we will have scenarios where say city is chnaged only and not others in that case, it should take values from old (i.e. if they dont have anu updates prior to the effective date).

Comment: Specifically, the caveat is for the case when there are multiple changes.  As in:  effective-date is 20.May.  Change on 25.May to all fields.  Change on 28.May to just city.  If you queried for 30.May it would pick up 28.May change, but then get the rest from the effective date of 20.May.  Is that relevant?  If they change just the city one time and leave everything else alone, it works just fine.  It's only the multiple stacked changes that would require expanding this code.

Comment: In the example you stated above, If you queried for 30 May. apart from getting changes for 28th may, if other fields are unchanged, it should get other fields from effective date as on 25th may. As on 30th may 20th may changes are outdated as there were chnages made on 25th may.

Comment: I think this may be sufficient then -- try it out and let me know.  (Must go to bed now, so you'd get follow-ups tomorrow morning, if any are needed. :) )

Comment: Pleas see the last comments I have posted for glen's answer. Same problem here in this query too.

Comment: OK, that's exactly the caveat case I described a couple comments ago -- the problem as before is that I only use the most recent change.  The date of the most recent change needs to be per field, not for the entire employee.  Will modify.

Comment: See the much rewritten answer to deal w/ dates varying by field.

Comment: Could we make it so that I dont have to give the effective date as input and query will just give the records for all the employees on different effective dates. So, result may have mutiple records for a single employee based on different effective dates?

Comment: Hey, sorry but the query is not working now. For any date it just returns the record from the employee table. No updates are aplied datewise :(

Comment: For the 2nd part -- in which the query isn't working -- could compare your data w/ the data in the sqlfiddle and show me what the difference is -- I get results and I'm presuming there's a data difference.

Comment: As I said before Could we make it so that I dont have to give the effective date as input and query will just give the records for all the employees on different effective dates. So, result may have mutiple records for a single employee based on different effective dates?

Comment: This may require query to chnage a lot i guess. realy stuck I am :(

Comment: .I am really stuck now. Please help.

Comment: I'd have to base it off of the original query -- I think I see how, but can't work on it until a bit later today.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table employee(emp_id int, name varchar(64), region varchar(64), country varchar(64), city varchar(64), effective_date date)
create table employee_updates(emp_id int, old varchar(64), new varchar(64), effective_date date, what varchar(64))

insert into employee values(1, 'james', 'asia', 'india', 'mumbai',to_date('2012-04-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into employee values(2, 'rick', 'americas', 'us', 'ny',to_date('2012-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));

insert into employee_updates values(1, 'asia', 'germany', to_date('2012-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'region');
insert into employee_updates values(1, 'india', 'germany', to_date('2012-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'country');
insert into employee_updates values(1, 'mumbai', 'munich', to_date('2012-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'city');

-- <UPDATE 3>
insert into employee values(3, 'jane', 'Europe', 'UK', 'London',to_date('2012-03-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
insert into employee_updates values(3, 'Europe', 'Canada', to_date('2012-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'region');
insert into employee_updates values(3, 'UK', 'Canada', to_date('2012-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'country');
insert into employee_updates values(3, 'London', 'Toronto', to_date('2012-11-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'city');
```

: Hopefully this is a bit more clear. It returns the full set of effective dated records:

```
 WITH combined_records AS (

   SELECT emp_id, name, region, country, city, effective_date
     FROM employee

   UNION

   -- Union with a set of pseudo employee records generated from the updates table
   -- Any of these new "employee" records could have a NULL value in one of the region/country/city fields

   -- 2. Compress the sparse matrix to merge records sharing common (emp_id + effective_date)
   SELECT x.emp_id, e.name, MAX(x.region) AS region, MAX(x.country) AS country, MAX(x.city) AS city, x.effective_date
     FROM ( -- 1. Create a sparse matrix of one row with each record from the updates table
            SELECT emp_id, effective_date
                  ,CASE WHEN WHAT = 'region' THEN NEW ELSE NULL END AS region
                  ,CASE WHEN WHAT = 'country' THEN NEW ELSE NULL END AS country
                  ,CASE WHEN WHAT = 'city' THEN NEW ELSE NULL END AS city
              FROM employee_updates
          ) x
         ,employee e
     WHERE e.emp_id = x.emp_id
     GROUP BY x.emp_id, e.name, x.effective_date

)


SELECT a.emp_id, a.name
      ,COALESCE(a.region, rgn.region) AS region
      ,COALESCE(a.country, cntry.country) AS country
      ,COALESCE(a.city, cty.city) AS city
      ,a.effective_date
  FROM combined_records a
      ,combined_records rgn
      ,combined_records cntry
      ,combined_records cty
  WHERE a.emp_id = rgn.emp_id
    AND rgn.effective_date = ( SELECT MAX(effective_date)
                                 FROM combined_records
                                 WHERE emp_id = a.emp_id
                                   AND region IS NOT NULL
                                   AND effective_date <= a.effective_date )
    AND a.emp_id = cntry.emp_id
    AND cntry.effective_date = ( SELECT MAX(effective_date)
                                 FROM combined_records
                                 WHERE emp_id = a.emp_id
                                   AND country IS NOT NULL
                                   AND effective_date <= a.effective_date )
    AND a.emp_id = cty.emp_id
    AND cty.effective_date = ( SELECT MAX(effective_date)
                                 FROM combined_records
                                 WHERE emp_id = a.emp_id
                                   AND city IS NOT NULL
                                   AND effective_date <= a.effective_date )
  ORDER BY emp_id, effective_date;
```

Output:

```
 emp_id | name  |  region  | country |  city   | effective_date
--------+-------+----------+---------+---------+----------------
      1 | james | asia     | india   | mumbai  | 2012-04-10
      1 | james | germany  | germany | munich  | 2012-05-01
      2 | rick  | americas | us      | ny      | 2012-03-01
      3 | jane  | Europe   | UK      | London  | 2012-03-01
      3 | jane  | Canada   | Canada  | London  | 2012-05-01
      3 | jane  | Canada   | Canada  | Toronto | 2012-11-01
(6 rows)
```

By the way, I used "effective_date" rather than "when". You are using keywords like "when" and "new" for columns that will just be confusing and cause grief.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not able to run this query. I am using Oracle. Error is unexpected end of SQL command.

Comment: the first part runs properly but when i try to run the second select statement i.e. select * from eff_emps i get error.

Comment: Ok I could run the query properly now. BUt there is a slight problem with the query. If i say effective_date as 10 dec then i m getting region and country as null instead of the latest which should be germany.

Comment: Worked for me. I modified the query a bit to handle the case where only one area changes (city or region or country) rather than requiring all 3 to change. I don't have an oracle instance to try on, but I don't see a problem with running this kind of query on Oracle.

Comment: Is it possible to get all employee records as on different effective dates instead of on a single effective date? e.g. emp 1 as on 10 Jun, emp 1 as on 15 Aug and emp 1 as on 20 sept all in one query. So I dont want to pass the effective date as you have done in second query. I just want to get the employee details as on different dates. and this  for all the employees. So result set will have duplicate entries for each employee but on a different effective dates.

Comment: Just chop off the last filter. ie SELECT * FROM eff_emps should do it already

Comment: Ok. I tried this query.  I'll try to tell the problem with example. emp1 has region asia as on today (25 May) and title as on developer, japan as on 1 aug in update table, russia as on 10 sep in update table, title changed from dev to TL as on 1 nov in update table. With your query as on nov I will get region as asia and title as TL, since there are no chnages for region in nov. It should pick aug changes. i.e. as on nov region = russia

Comment: I see what you are saying. That is because the COALESCE is basing default values on the existing EMPLOYEE table. Really, it needs to base defaults on the EFF_EMPS table instead. So the COALESCE needs to come out of the subquery, leaving possible NULLs in EFF_EMPS. The NULLs need to be looked after in a similar fashion as the MAX(eff_date) is done. Sorry, I can't make the change now. Perhaps tonight, if I get back in on time.  Cheers.

Comment: Hey I still have the same issue updates are proper till there are updates till that date but aftewards it defaults to record from employee table. (from earliar coment  i.e. as on nov region = russia –->> it still says asia )

Comment: Please Please Please Please Help :(

Comment: @Ashish Ugly as heck, but this one builds a view of based on a union of employee and updates, then replaces nulls based on the view rather than the employee table.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE P_GET_EMP_UPDATED(edate date) AS
 emp_rec emp_up%rowtype;
 query VARCHAR2(100);    
CURSOR emp_cur IS SELECT * FROM emp_up WHERE eff_date <= edate and eff_date >= sysdate; 
 BEGIN 
   OPEN emp_cur; 
   LOOP 
   FETCH emp_cur INTO emp_rec; 
   EXIT WHEN emp_cur%NOTFOUND;             
  -- query  := 'update emp set '||emp_rec.what||' =  ''' || emp_rec.new || ''' where empid = '|| emp_rec.empid;    
   --dbms_output.put_line (query); 

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  'update emp set '||emp_rec.what||' =  ''' || emp_rec.new || ''' where empid = '|| emp_rec.empid;

 END LOOP;   
 END P_GET_EMP_UPDATED;
```

This procedure will update the emp table till required date.Then rollback it back

```
  SAVEPOINT Emp_modify;
 --call procedure
  execute p_get_emp_updated(to_date('2012-06-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
  select * from emp;  --These rows are from the temprorily updated table
  rollback to SAVEPOINT Emp_modify;
```

select * from emp;  //This will give the original emp table

Comment: Thsi is very risky to modify the main table. There will be constantly updates will be made to the table.